# Angular canActive() not return value?

Tags: angular

Help me check code below . What wrong ?

```
this.authenticationService.isLogin().subscribe(s => {
            if (s == 10) {
                this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
                return false;
            }
        }, e => {
            // console.log(e);
            return true;
        })
```

Comment: Does this code belongs to `canActive()` route gaurd ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `subscribe` to the Observable, it will be consumed. What you should be doing instead is transform the value wrapped by the Observable using the `map` operator.

Here, give this a try:

IF you're using Rxjs 5.5 or newer:

```
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

...
return this.authenticationService.isLogin().pipe(
  map(s => {
    if (s == 10) {
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      return false;
    } else {
      // Not sure if this is what you want to return. 
      // But there needs to be an else condition as well for this.
      return true;
    }
  }),
  catchError(error => of(true))
)
```

If you're using Rxjs 5 or earlier:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
...
return this.authenticationService.isLogin()
  .map(s => {
    if (s == 10) {
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      return false;
    }  else {
      // Not sure if this is what you want to return. 
      // But there needs to be an else condition as well for this.
      return true;
    }
  });
```

Comment: nice. I will try !